# Text in flash button symbols all change at once (Actionscript 2)

Tags: button, flash, actionscript-2

I have reached an impass which means I have to spend many hours doing something in a very tedious way because I can't work out a way to do it quickly, here is my problem.

In flash if I make a button that consists of a rectangle and a text field then make it all a button symbol, if I then copy the symbol to multiple instances on screen and change the text in one of them, it changes in all of them because I am changing the symbol.

How can I overcome this, perhaps with actionscript? I tried writing.
button1.text1.text = "test change button text"; on the main canvas (and giving one button a name of button one and the text field within it text1) but it doesn't work.

The only thing I found that works was to make multiple symbol copies of the button but then if I want to change the colour or dimensions of all the buttons it takes ages.

Is there a better way? Using actionscript 2 perhaps, or just some property of the button to allow individual text?

Answer (score 0):

I attempted your situation... and I didn't run into your problem. Text boxes are individual values, provided that the text box is dynamic or input

I think that what may solve your problem is checking what kind of text boxes you are working with. Look in the properties panel; does it say "dynamic"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it is set to dynamic. I took a screenshot but it said I don't have a high enough rep yet to post images (I've only just joined stackoverflow). I am using a program called Sothink Quicker, I like it because it's very similar to the old macromedia flash and quite affordable. But I can't quite seem to solve this problem.

Comment: Ok I found a workaround - to put text fields on top of the buttons. I hope it's not too bad for seo.